# ElasticSearch, Nest and timeout for long queries

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using ElasticSearch with Nest (0.9.16) and have some queries which take longer than 60 seconds.  When that happens, I receive the following error:

> The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

While I am concerned that the query is taking such a long time, for this question, I am just interested if there is a way to increase the timeout.  I have not been able to find a way to increase the timeout.

Note, I do see a couple of places where I can set a timeout, but these are not the right places:

```cs
var setting = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(searchUrl)).SetTimeout(200000);
```

or

```cs
searchdescriptor.Timeout("120000");
```

The first one sets the connection timeout and the second one sets the ElasticSearch timeout, both of which are not helpful here.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 7):

Actually, much to my chagrin, the ConnectionSettings().SetTimeout() does in fact increase the request timeout and solve my problem. I am not sure why I missed this initially.